# How to call back a parents name from child table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as follows:

games

```
id | game_name | console_id
    1     God of War     1
    2     Zelda          3
    3     Sonic          4
```

consoles

```
id | console_name 
1    PS4
2    Xbox
3    Switch
4    Mega Drive
```

I've linked them via the Designer view so when I go to insert a name game (I'm doing this via the phpMyAdmin control panel) as soon as I click on "console_id" it gives me a drop down of 1 - PS4, 2 - Xbox and so on. So the games table can now read from consoles table no problem so I think I've got everything correct from that side of things.

Now I can run this code

> SELECT id, game_name, console_id FROM games

and I will get the output

> 1 - God of war - 1

What I would like to do is something like this:

> SELECT id, game_name, console_id.**console_name** FROM games

So instead of it saying God of war is on console ID 1, it says its on console.name PS4.

How can I do it, as I thought by linking the tables it would allow me to do it.

Comment: One small remark on your design: the relation being a many to many, you may want to use a third table with only foreign keys (or even better an additional primary key) in it so that you can easily represent for exemple the case of Fifa 2019 being available on all consoles. If this is not an exercise and this code is going to evolve, it will save you the effort of refactoring very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a JOIN between the tables.  In this case, you want to join the `consoles` table to the `games` table by matching the `id` field of the former to the `console_id` field of the latter, like this:

```
SELECT g.id, g.game_name, c.console_name
FROM games g
INNER JOIN consoles c
  ON c.id = g.console_id
```

Comment: Perfect, This has worked and now I understand what I need to do can can build on that from here. Thanks a lot Paul!